# speed up data insertion 

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL database.

If I have **6,000,000 new records** need to be **inserted into a table** (not a empty table).

**Question 1:**

Is

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9), ... ...

ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS;
OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name;
```

**faster** than:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3)
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3)
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3)
...
...

ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS;
OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name;
```

?

**Question 2:**

Is the first one called bulk insertion?

**-----------Update---------------**

Should I **enable/disable keys** and **optimize** my table after? As @ Neil 's comment seems do not recommend to do so. What is others' opinion?

Comment: why you want to do that? you don't speed up you slow down when you optimize the table

Comment: Neil, I want to insert a large amount of data into a table. Do you mean they are the same speed, and I should not optimize the table after a large insertion? Can you explain why I should not optimize the table?

Comment: optimize table is good to do but why disabling the key and enabling them? if you do a massive inserts, i am guessing the table wont be use right?

Comment: I disable the key to temporarily remove the indexes in order to speed up large data insertion, what is wrong with that? Isn't it a convention to disable key when insert a large amount of data? Do you think the disable/enable key won't help with insertion speed?? Besides, my question is most on the definition of bulk insertion and is it faster than normal insertion.

Comment: Should I enable/disable keys and optimize my table after that? As @ Neil 's comment seems do not recommend to do so. What is others' opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to optimize your queries using bulk inserts. This should considerably increase the speed of the inserting data process.

You wrote that you had encountered an error on inserting large amount of data - **'database gone away'**.

In this case **the size of the query should not exceed the maximal size of the packet** - see the information about the max_allowed_packet variable.

---

How to check max_allowed_packet value -

```
SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet;
```

How to set this value -

```
SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = 200000;
```

[More information here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

If all this not enough for you, then have a look at this article (as Gfox suggested) - [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html).

Comment: where can I check the  max_allowed_packet variable? And should I disablea & enable keys during insertion. And should I optimize table after all insertions have done?

Comment: Does the "packet" means one value in bulk insertion?

Comment: No, packet it is a buffer (array of bytes) that is send to the server. You should care about this length when you build your bulk-INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

[Please refer to this article.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

By sending one query you will save several steps and win time. Specially when there is a question of insertion of hundred thousands of rows this time difference will be significant.

Comment: I am using MySQL database. How can I check if my table is a transactional one or nontransactional one? Since the article you linked has some concept of block the table before insertion if it is a nontransactional one.

Comment: Should I enable/disable keys and optimize my table after that? As Neil 's comment seems do not recommend to do so. What is your opinion?

Comment: Well , disabling keys is necessary in the case when deleting of data is needed. In that case you can delete co-related data. But in the case of inserting data it won't make much difference.

Comment: @ Gfox, but optimize table after large insertion of data is necessary in my case right?

Answer (score 1):

i Think Sending one query is more faster but With 6,000,000 record ,

`Database will have problems` ,

as i tried on windows ` insert 1000000 record as one query ,

i got this error      `database gone away :(`

Comment: Is it a common problem in MySQL or is it only happened on you? Is there any documentation mentioned this ?

Comment: really ,I don't know , `but to me and as i tried on windows`         this error happened :(

Comment: Should I enable/disable keys and optimize my table after that? As Neil 's comment seems do not recommend to do so. What is your opinion?

Comment: i think this comment is very useful , `http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,68820,68939#msg-68939` and try to read the main post here `http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,68820,68820`

Comment: Mona , I have read the link you provided already yesterday, they are always "maybe" the situation, which makes me confused about should I disable key and optimize table

Comment: Maybe it is better not the disable keys when you have records in the table already.